# I can't append my external/custom JS for my sidebar in Vue Web JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli

I already have template but it just dummy data, i want to migration this template to vue version . But the problem is come from my custom js , which is the part of my sidebarand must to linked by this custom js .

i had tried include my custom js in App.vue with code like this

but that didn't work either. And I have also tried it on my index.html however doesn't work too

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="wrapper">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <Sidebar />
    <div id="content">
      <Navbar />
      <router-view/>
    </div>
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
  </div>
</template>
```

and also i've been tried another way like bellow here

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="wrapper">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <Sidebar />
    <div id="content">
      <Navbar />
      <router-view/>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(".disabled").addClass("disabledbutton");

      $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
              $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
          });
      });
    </script>
  </div>
</template>
```

rather difficult to describe it through writing, because this code serves to make the sidebar interactive . As other sidebar, able to open and close .

Comment: do you get an error like `Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, as they will not be parsed.` in the developer tools console?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the response I got

Comment: you are already using Vue, why still using jQuery? these can simply port to Vue code.

Comment: which means jquery doesn't apply in vue applications, is that so?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that - I'm sure there are still some very tiny uses of jquery